# How to Assert value in grid using Flaui

Tags: f#

After the following line, what functions needs to be used to assert value in grid:
`FindFirstDescendant(conditionFactory.ByAutomationId("2006"))`

Already tried this:
`FindFirstDescendant(conditionFactory.ByAutomationId("2006")).AsDataGridView().AsGridCell()`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqOiT.png)

in the above pane I need to assert the value, and the pane automation ID is "2006" what function and parameters I have to use for that.
that entire grid is pane and all the values in that are referred as document. you can see here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeQvj.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question needs more information and clarity, though.

Comment: updated my question with adding the image and written what I need to do with that.